# Difference and meaning of isopointal and isoconfigurational structures

Tags: crystallography, symmetry

These are the meanings I`ve found, but I do not completely understand them.
Isopointal: Two structures that have the same space-group type or belong to a pair of enantiomorphic space groups. And that the complete sequence of the occupied Wyckoff positions is the same for both structures when the structural data have been standarized.

Isoconfigurational:Isopointal and for all corresponding Wyckoff positions, both the crystallographic configurations (crystallographic orbits) and their  geometric interrelationships are similar.

I do not understand the difference regarding the Wyckoff positions. I thought that if the atomic positions in the Wyckoff positions are the same then, the configuration is also the same. Peharps the problem is that I do not know what a configuration actually means. If someone could give a brief explanation I would be grateful.

Thanks!